# MongoServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND at Timeout._onTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, discord.js

So you may have seen this question type somewhere else. but the thing here is I tried all of the things we need to do according to docs and saw other posts with similar errors but still my error is not fixed. So I use keyv and use MongoDB atlas as storage adapter in this code, but the error is from MongoDB. Also, there is no error in the "keyv" because it works for other people, there is error in the MongoDB

So now I will list whatever I tried:

```
1. Made sure there is IP access
2. The userid and passcode are correct 
3. The MongoDB atlas is running 
4. Read the docs and code multiple times
5. If u think adding the +srv with the code will fix the error, it won't, it doesn't work with keyql idk why also it is not present in many codes, I already tried it
```

So this is the code

```js
const { Client, Intents, MessageEmbed, Collection } = require('discord.js');
let client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const Keyv = require('keyv');
const keyv = new Keyv('mongodb://Discord:password@cluster0.auifa.mongodb.net/Cluster0');
dotenv.config();

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});


client.on('messageCreate', async (msg) => {
     if (msg.author.bot) return;
    let number = msg.content.split(' ')[1];
    if (msg.content === '!ping') {
        msg.channel.send('ping!')
    }

    
// Use like const prefix = await getGuildPrefix(); `
    const getGuildPrefix = async () => {
        const prefixMap = await keyv.get('prefix');
        return prefixMap ?. [msg.guild.id] || "!"
    }

// Sets the prefix to the current guild.
    const setGuildPrefix = async (prefix) => {
        let prefixMap = await keyv.get('prefix');
        if (!prefixMap)
    {
     prefixMap = "!";
    }
        prefixMap[msg.guild.id] = prefix;
        await keyv.set('prefix', `${prefixMap}`);
    }

    let prefix = await getGuildPrefix();
// Get prefix command.
    if ((msg.content === `${process.env.prefix}prefix`) || (msg.content === `${prefix}prefix`)) {
        msg.channel.send(`Your server prefix is ${prefix}`)
    }

// Change prefix command
    const commandPrefix = await getGuildPrefix();
    if ((msg.content.startsWith(`${process.env.prefix}setprefix`)) || (msg.content.startsWith(`${commandPrefix}setprefix`))) {
        const newPrefix = number;

        if (newPrefix.length === 0) {
            msg.channel.send(`Please enter a valid prefix`);
        }

        await setGuildPrefix(newPrefix)
        msg.channel.send(`Your server prefix is now '${newPrefix}'`);
    }
})
client.login(process.env.token);
```

And this is the error message

```
Keyv connection error: MongoServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND cluster0.auifa.mongodb.net
    at Timeout._onTimeout (D:\javascript\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\topology.js:438:30)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription
```

Answer (score 1):

Connection string does not look like an Atlas one.
It has to be something like: `mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.auifa.mongodb.net/YOUR-DB`

Login to your Atlas account then:

1. Go to Databases page
2. Click on Connect button
3. Choose "Connect your application"
4. Copy your connection string

Docs about Mongo Atlas connection: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/connect-to-cluster/#connect-to-a-cluster

Comment: Read 4th and 5th points in what i tried, i tried it but it doesn't work idk why

Comment: because Keyv use mongojs instead of official MongoDB drivers: https://github.com/jaredwray/keyv-mongo/issues/32#issuecomment-765324556

Comment: yes it is the same format i gave in the code (line 5 in the code), i said i tried both

Comment: use this version:
"dependencies": {
    "@keyv/mongo": "github:darovic/keyv-mongo",

Comment: Already did that too

Comment: Did you try last version too?

Comment: yes, i tried the version 2.2 and 4.0